# Can I create openssl EC_KEY when I have public key in HEX format using c++

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, cryptography

Host(PC APP) sends the client a random number and client (device) signs this random number with its private key. This signature in HEX format and public key in HEX format is sent to PC APP for verification. I am having trouble converting the public key in HEX format to EC_KEY which structure in openssl.

I have tried following things
1. Convert from HEX to ascii and  then from ascii to base64 and read the key with PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY. 
2. I have tried to use BN_hex2bn to get x and y components of the key and then use EC_KEY_set_public_key_affine_coordinates.

None of these seem to work for me.

```
bool OpensslUtility::computeSHA256Hash(const std::string& unhashed, std::string& hashed)
{
    bool success = false;

    EVP_MD_CTX* context = EVP_MD_CTX_new();

    if (context != NULL)
    {
        if (EVP_DigestInit_ex(context, EVP_sha256(), NULL))
        {
            if (EVP_DigestUpdate(context, unhashed.c_str(), unhashed.length()))
            {
                unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
                unsigned int lengthOfHash = 0;

                if (EVP_DigestFinal_ex(context, hash, &lengthOfHash))
                {
                    std::stringstream ss;
                    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lengthOfHash; ++i)
                    {
                        ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)hash[i];
                    }

                    hashed = ss.str();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        }
        convertToUpperCase(hashed);
        EVP_MD_CTX_free(context);
    }

    return success;
}

void Example1()
{
    std::unique_ptr< ECDSA_SIG, std::function<void(ECDSA_SIG*)>> zSignature(ECDSA_SIG_new(), [](ECDSA_SIG* b) { ECDSA_SIG_free(b); });
    // Set up the signature... 
    BIGNUM* rr = NULL, * ss = NULL;

    std::string sSignatureR = "1B87DA77F29B7C891436B5477BFFBA919EDF42167F27EB525B94EB0A4D295FE8";
    std::string sSignatureS = "6E80B434A88D8609E63D3B2FA4E171C428CCAABEF84F5ECDB646E99AAE095983";

    BN_hex2bn(&rr, sSignatureR.c_str());
    BN_hex2bn(&ss, sSignatureS.c_str());

    ECDSA_SIG_set0(zSignature.get(), rr, ss);

    // Set up the public key.... 
    const char* sPubKeyString = "E3A7E51FE102286D071026111088F680761FDCD7031E3D56244BBE07451601E78AD08AD40EADCF380900985A1FAB94DE6D02DB91920F1144E9EBC4E248444969";

    char cx[65];
    BIGNUM* gx = NULL;
    BIGNUM* gy = NULL;

    std::unique_ptr< EC_KEY, std::function<void(EC_KEY*)>> zPublicKey(EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1), [](EC_KEY* b) { EC_KEY_free(b); });
    EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(zPublicKey.get(), OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);
    memcpy(cx, sPubKeyString, 64);
    cx[64] = 0;

    if (!BN_hex2bn(&gx, cx)) {
        std::cout << "Error getting to binary format" << std::endl;
    }

    if (!BN_hex2bn(&gy, &sPubKeyString[64])) {
        std::cout << "Error getting to binary format" << std::endl;
    }

    if (!EC_KEY_set_public_key_affine_coordinates(zPublicKey.get(), gx, gy)) {
        std::cout << "setting public key attributes" << std::endl;
    }

    EC_KEY* pPubKey = zPublicKey.get();
    //PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY(bo.get(), &pPubKey, NULL, NULL);


    if (EC_KEY_check_key(pPubKey) == 1)
    {
        printf("EC Key valid.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("EC Key Invalid!\n");
    }

    std::string sRandomNumber = "bef2fc87919a11d8312dc118ece116b108377aa4d771b1c1e5aaed41b85d50"; //Message to sign (Given to arduino.....)

    std::string sHash;
    OpensslUtility::computeSHA256Hash(sRandomNumber, sHash);

    int iVerify = OpensslUtility::verify_signature((const unsigned char*)sHash.c_str(), zSignature.get(), pPubKey);

}



std::string OpensslUtility::HexToBytes(const std::string& hex)
{
    std::string bytes;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
        std::string byteString = hex.substr(i, 2);
        char byte = (char)strtol(byteString.c_str(), NULL, 16);
        bytes.push_back(byte);
    }

    return bytes;
}

int OpensslUtility::verify_signature(const unsigned char* hash, const ECDSA_SIG* signature, EC_KEY* eckey)
{
    int verify_status = ECDSA_do_verify(hash, strlen((const char*)hash), signature, eckey);
    if (1 != verify_status)
    {
        printf("Failed to verify EC Signature\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Verifed EC Signature\n");

    return 1;
}

std::string OpensslUtility::base64(const char* input, int length)
{
    std::unique_ptr< BIO, std::function<void(BIO*)>> b64(BIO_new(BIO_f_base64()), [](BIO* b) { BIO_free(b); });
    std::unique_ptr< BIO, std::function<void(BIO*)>> bmem(BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()), [](BIO* b) { BIO_free(b); });

    BUF_MEM* bptr;
    BIO* b64_ptr = b64.get();

    b64_ptr = BIO_push(b64.get(), bmem.get());
    BIO_write(b64_ptr, input, length);
    BIO_flush(b64_ptr);
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64_ptr, &bptr);

    std::unique_ptr< char, std::function<void(char*)>> buff((char*)malloc(bptr->length), [](char* b) { free(b); });

    memcpy(buff.get(), bptr->data, bptr->length - 1);
    buff.get()[bptr->length - 1] = 0;
    std::string sTo64(buff.get());

    return sTo64;
}


void Example2()
{
    std::unique_ptr< ECDSA_SIG, std::function<void(ECDSA_SIG*)>> zSignature(ECDSA_SIG_new(), [](ECDSA_SIG* b) { ECDSA_SIG_free(b); });
    // Set up the signature... 
    BIGNUM* rr = NULL, * ss = NULL;

    std::string sSignatureR = "1B87DA77F29B7C891436B5477BFFBA919EDF42167F27EB525B94EB0A4D295FE8";
    std::string sSignatureS = "6E80B434A88D8609E63D3B2FA4E171C428CCAABEF84F5ECDB646E99AAE095983";

    BN_hex2bn(&rr, sSignatureR.c_str());
    BN_hex2bn(&ss, sSignatureS.c_str());

    ECDSA_SIG_set0(zSignature.get(), rr, ss);

    // Set up the public key.... 
    const char* sPubKeyString = "E3A7E51FE102286D071026111088F680761FDCD7031E3D56244BBE07451601E78AD08AD40EADCF380900985A1FAB94DE6D02DB91920F1144E9EBC4E248444969";

    std::unique_ptr< EC_KEY, std::function<void(EC_KEY*)>> zPublicKey(EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1), [](EC_KEY* b) { EC_KEY_free(b); });
    EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(zPublicKey.get(), OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);

    EC_KEY* pPubKey = zPublicKey.get();


    std::string sKeyInAscii = OpensslUtility::HexToBytes(sPubKeyString);
    std::string sPub64(base64_encode(sKeyInAscii));
    std::string sKeyInPem = std::string("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n") + sPub64 + std::string("\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");

    const char* pzKey = sKeyInPem.c_str();
    std::unique_ptr< BIO, std::function<void(BIO*)>> bo(BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()), [](BIO* b) { BIO_free(b); });
    BIO_write(bo.get(), pzKey, strlen(pzKey));

    EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(zPublicKey.get(), OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);

    PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY(bo.get(), &pPubKey, NULL, NULL);


    if (EC_KEY_check_key(pPubKey) == 1)
    {
        printf("EC Key valid.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("EC Key Invalid!\n");
    }

    std::string sRandomNumber = "bef2fc87919a11d8312dc118ece116b108377aa4d771b1c1e5aaed41b85d50"; //Message to sign (Given to arduino.....)

    std::string sHash;
    OpensslUtility::computeSHA256Hash(sRandomNumber, sHash);

    int iVerify = OpensslUtility::verify_signature((const unsigned char*)sHash.c_str(), zSignature.get(), pPubKey);

}
```

Comment: Example1() and Example2() are the two ways in which I am trying to create public key in openssl from HEX format.

Comment: So when you say it doesn't work - what exactly happens?

Comment: In Example1() -> The signature is not verified.

Comment: In Example2() -> The key is not valid. I get EC Key Invalid

Comment: Example1() is obviously the right way to create the key. The EC_KEY_check_key() call would not succeed unless the key was correct (and this is highly unlikely to happen by chance). You don't show the "verify_signature" function so the problem could be there. Also the "computeSHA256Hash" function looks "odd", since you seem to convert the hash result into hex at the end for some reason. Without looking at the verify_signature function it is difficult to tell whether this is correct.

Comment: It would be more usual to use EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY() to create an EVP_PKEY, and then verify the signature with the EVP_DigestVerify* functions. This does all the hashing and signature verification in one step. You would need the signature in a binary format first using i2d_ECDSA_SIG().

Comment: I have added verify_signature function.

Comment: The "computeSHA256Hash" function looks deeply suspect to me. The conversion to hex that you do at the end is almost certainly incorrect. Normally you would pass the binary output from a SHA256 digest direct to the ECDSA verification function. You cannot sign a message longer than 256 bits with the P-256 curve that you are using. Anything longer than that is truncated. SHA256 creates 256 bits of output - but your hex conversion doubles that to 512 bits.

Comment: I'm also suspicious of the message format. Are you sure its the random number in hex format that has been signed? Or is it the random number in binary format that is signed (and in that case is it in big-endian or little-endian form)?

Comment: You were right... .the hex conversion in computeSHA256Hash is wrong. I removed that part and now the verification is working as expected. Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Comment: Note that hexadecimal is a way of representing binary data for places where a string is required, e.g. for human consumption. Hexadecimals is the string representation of the binary bytes. If binary is required and you have hexadecimals, then you must convert the hexadecimal character string to an octet string / byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must set group and point

```
EC_POINT* Hex_to_point_NID_secp256k1(char* str) {
   EC_KEY* ecKey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
   const EC_GROUP* ecGroup = EC_KEY_get0_group(ecKey);
   EC_POINT* ecPoint = EC_POINT_hex2point(ecGroup, str, NULL, NULL);
   return ecPoint;
}
```

Then

```
EC_KEY* pubKey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
EC_KEY_set_public_key(pubKey, Hex_to_point_NID_secp256k1(hexPublicKey));
```